# Issue keeping the chip select asserted low during transfer

Tags: spi

I am working with a SPI device on the Raspberry Pi 2, and am encountering an issue where the chip select line is asserting high mid-way through the transfer. Is this because the CS line is not pulled low hard enough? Is there any way to fix this? I am using the `py-spidev` library to communicate. I have had no problems communicating with this device via SPI using an Arduino Trinket Pro (3v3).

Below is a screenshot from my Saleae:

[image]

EDIT:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lms22.png): Add code

```
import spidev
import time

spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.mode = 1
spi.max_speed_hz = 500000

spi.open(0, 1)

def on():
    spi.xfer([0x03])
    time.sleep(9e-3)
    spi.xfer([0x00, 0x01])

def off():
    spi.xfer([0x03])
    time.sleep(9e-3)
    spi.xfer([0x01])

# Turn the device on and then off
on()
time.sleep(3)
off()
```

Comment: Hi, I do not understand. CS is channel 3? In the captured signal I cannot see anything strange wrt channel 3.

Comment: Yes. At around 65 us or so, the CS is going high, when it should remain low the entire transfer.

Comment: This is the part that I do not understand ;) What's the upper part of the diagram und what's the lower? The lower looks like "real measurement"... and does not show that glitch.

Comment: That's a great question. They are supposed to be the same..I will try and give Saleae a call to see if it's an issue with their firmware or something. I'm pretty sure it's an artifact though..because the data transfer does not always go through (sometimes it does, though!)

Comment: You might want to include a relevant snippet of code, if only to demonstrate there is nothing weird about it.

Comment: BTW. are you reading or writing in this case? Just wondering because the supposed CS glitch is at the very moment MOSI changes too.

Comment: It is my understanding that it reads/writes simultaneously. So I am writing (sending the commands to turn the device on/off), but expect back some bytes that tell me whether it worked or not.

Comment: How often does this glitch happen?

Comment: @joan I would say every two-three times I send any command, it happens

Comment: So in a crazy turn of events...I unplugged the Saleae Logic Analyzer and the device works..I (obviously) can't confirm that the SS is being held low throughout anymore, but it seems as though the logic analyzer itself was the problem?

Comment: Well at least it *should not* be the problem as the LA inputs really should be high-impedance.